# Javascript: Connecting html and js files

Tags: javascript

I'm tring to understand how to connected my html with another file js, but the issues is with this software call topsytle4 it a trail basic,but for some reason it show the file but no feature can be us that could be use.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Can you try editing your question and asking in a different way?  Do you just need to know how to use a `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Add this line between `<head>` and `</head>`:

```
<script src="your_js_path_here"></script>
```